# Python 3.5.1 : How to check whether openpyxl package exist and if it does not exist how to download and install it "within" the script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I started writing python codes two weeks ago and until now I have manipulated some excel data after converting it to txt file. Now, I want to manipulate excel data directly, so I need to install openpyxl package. However, my script will be used in many different places and computers (Note that: all of them use either OS X or a Linux distrubution) which might (probably do not) contain openpyxl package installed. I want my script to check whether this package exist, and if it does not exit, then download and install it.

For that purpose, as I searched and found that I could check the existence of the package by first importing the pip module and then pip.get_installed_distributions() method. However, I am not sure whether I am in a wrong way or not. Besides, I have no idea how to download and install openpyxl package "without leaving the script".

Would you like to help me ?

Comment: See [How do I automatically install missing python modules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120902/how-do-i-automatically-install-missing-python-modules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting ahead of yourself by trying to solve a deployment problem when you don't have the software to deploy.

Having a script trying to manage its own deployment is generally a bad idea because it takes responsibility away from package managers.

Here is my answer to your question:

1. Build your software **under the assumption that all packages are installed/deployed correctly**. I recommend creating a `virtualenv` (virtual environment) on your development computer, using pip to install `openpyxl` and any other packages you need.
2. Once your software is built and functional, read up on how to deploy your software package to PyPi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi. Create your package by defining `openpyxl` as a dependency, ensure your package can be installed/run properly (I recommend adding in tests), then deploy to PyPi so anyone can use your software.

If you want to add a nice layer of validation in your script *just in case*, add the following to your `main` method:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
try:
    import openpyxl
except ImportError as iE:
    print("Python Excel module 'openpyxl' not found")
    sys.exit(1)

... rest of script ...
```

Comment: I forgot to clarify in my answer... the hashbang `#!/usr/bin/env python3` is something that goes at the top of the script **file**, not in a method, so omit that line if you are putting the code in a function.