# Providing a custom command class to setup.py in a separately installed package

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, setup.py

I am trying to create a python package that implements a custom command class for `setuptools.setup()` for use in other, unrelated packages' *setup.py* scripts. Ideally, I would like to be able to include this package in the `setup_requires` argument to `setup()`, and have the custom command class take effect before the remainder of the setup activities are performed. Does `setup()` provide a hook of some sort to support this use case? If not, how can I minimize the amount of boilerplate that has to appear in the *setup.py* script when using my package while still guaranteeing that my package will be available during setup? This is for an automation framework I am building, so minimizing the impact on the client packages' code and any dependence on end-user actions is a must.

Here is some example code...

In *my_custom_setup_package*:

```
from setuptools.command.install import install as _install

class install(_install):

    def run(self):
        result = super().run()

        # If the installed package has the required hooks:
            # Perform some custom post-installation actions
```

In the *setup.py* for *client_package*:

```
from setuptools import setup

# No cmdclass argument is given, because I can't count on
# my_custom_setup_package to be installed yet.
setup(
    ...
    setup_requires=['my_custom_setup_package'],
    ...
)
```

When running `python setup.py install` for *client_package*, the custom installation actions defined in *my_custom_setup_package* should get executed immediately after installation, even if *my_custom_setup_package* was not installed before the command was executed.

Any help is appreciated, even if it is to point me in a new direction altogether.

Comment: Immediately **after** installation?  Doesn't [install_requires](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/requirements/) specify things that need to be installed **before** or am I confusing it with something else?

Comment: The package I am building needs to be installed by the hypothetical other script's setup() *before* the installation, as a setup requirement, so that the *post*-installation actions can be performed automatically.

Comment: FYI, I mistakenly wrote `install_requires` in my sample code, when I meant `setup_requires`. I have edited the question accordingly.